# How to set child div 100% height of the parent (Foundation 6)?

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

There are three 33% divs next to eachother. The 1st is an empty div, the 2nd a div containing four images, and the 3rd empty div.

How do I responsively keep these 3 blocks the same height? I'm using Foundation 6.

[image]

```css
.block {
  background: grey;
}

.block, .imgBlock {
    height: 200px;
}

.imgBlock .row .column{
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/foundation/6.2.0/foundation.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.2.3/foundation.min.js"></script>

<div class="row small-up-3">
  <div class="column block">
  </div>
  <div class="column imgBlock">
    <div class="row small-up-2">
      <div class="column">
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/150"/>
      </div>
      <div class="column">
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/150"/>
      </div>
      <div class="column">
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/150"/>
      </div>
      <div class="column">
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/150"/>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column block">
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: Have you looked at the [equalizer feature](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/v/5.5.3/components/equalizer.html) in Foundation 6?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use foundation equalizer js. Here is your code using foundation equalizer:

**Code:**

```js
$(document).foundation();
```

```css
.block {
  background: grey;
}
.block,
.imgBlock {
  height: 200px;
}
.imgBlock .row .column {
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/foundation/6.2.0/foundation.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.2.3/foundation.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.2.3/plugins/foundation.equalizer.js"></script>
<div class="row small-up-3" data-equalizer>
  <div class="column block" data-equalizer-watch>
  </div>
  <div class="column imgBlock" data-equalizer-watch>
    <div class="row small-up-2">
      <div class="column">
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/150" />
      </div>
      <div class="column">
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/150" />
      </div>
      <div class="column">
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/150" />
      </div>
      <div class="column">
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/150" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column block" data-equalizer-watch>
  </div>

</div>
```